# Google service account .json key where stored on Windows

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console

I've created a service account at Google Play Api Page as well the .json key, it sent me a message - Private key saved to your computer, but i'm not able to find where JSON could be downloaded. 
What is the local path where google save the key on Windows PC's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fault of https://console.developers.google.com to load properly on some browsers or vice-versa.
It happened with me when I used Microsoft Edge Browser. I was frustrated to find that saved key. The fix was to change the browser and I tested the procedure of generating the key within Chrome and you know what happened? Voilá! It prompted to save as the key to my computer. :-)

If my fix, helped you, please, accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ВладимирВойтеховский Please, mark it as an answer with green check.